# How to rotate images in an array and save the image via a function

Tags: php, function, foreach

I am trying to create code to take a list of images and rotate them all using a function, I have tested the rotate function in my code with a single image and it works perfectly, image.inc.php function is also working creating the list of image names, the problem I am having is combining the two.

I have run various tests and I know my $filename var is being passed to the rotate function but I am missing something,firebug is showing this as the output...

```
<img src="http://localhost/Rotate-images/Rotate.php" alt="The image “http://localhost/Rotate-images/Rotate.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.">
```

I am also not sure what to use with my $saveto var for multiple images.

Any help appreciated figuring this one out, I'm a little rusty with my PHP so its probably staring me in the face.

```
<?php
require('includes/img.inc.php');

//Rotate image function
function RotateJpg($filename,$angle = 0,$savename = false)
{
    // Your original file
    $original   =   imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    // Rotate
    $rotated    =   imagerotate($original, $angle, 0);
    // If you have no destination, save to browser
    if($savename == false) {
            imagejpeg($rotated);
        }
    else
        // Save to a directory with a new filename
        imagejpeg($rotated,$savename);

    // Standard destroy command
    imagedestroy($rotated);
}

//Select image directory
$root = '';
// use if specifying path from root 
//$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//$path = '/images/rotator/';
$path = '../images/';

//Obtain list of images from directory 
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);

//Set default counter value
$counter = 0;

//Pass image list to function
foreach ($imgList as $value) {

//Advance counter by 1
$counter = $counter +1;

//Base image
$filename = $path.$value;

//Destination, including document root (you may have a defined root to use)
$saveto = "../images/test".$counter.".jpg";

//Run function
RotateJpg($filename,-90,$saveto);

}
?>
```

Comment: I think this may be an issue with your header. You can't normally output anything before the header is set. Is this happening?

Comment: Im not using the header, the two bits of code I used worked without

Comment: Remove             header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); and test again

Comment: Doh and here I was saying I don't use header, ok moved me on to an undefined variable on line 45 $saveto, hmm

Comment: All working now, thanks for the comments, I have edited to show finished code should anyone need it.